# Python Loop Unable to interrupt

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, iteration

I'm making a curency converter, time converter and weather app for an year 12 computer sciences project. Im unable to interrupt the loop that is being used for the main menu/location selector.
Can anyone help?
The code is below.

```
##This program is intended to help travellers with date and currency conversions ##
##Changelog----->##
##V1 - Include code for Forex Converter, code modified from - https://www.w3schools.in/python/examples/real-time-currency-converter##
##V2 - Implement GUI##
##V2.1 - Implement Multiple Screens GUI##
##V3 - Remove all GUI aspects##
##V3.1 - Create initial loop##

##Import Modules##
from forex_python.converter import CurrencyRates
import time
import datetime
import python_weather
import asyncio



##Opening info##
##V3.1##
global enter
enter = 'GO'
while enter == 'GO':
    print("========================================================================================================================================================================================")
    print("")
    print("Welcome to the Traveller Assisstant. This program is able to help you with currency conversions, date and time conversions and viewing weather details of your destination.")
    print("")
    print("========================================================================================================================================================================================")
    time.sleep(2.5)
    ori = str(input("Please enter your current country: "))
    dest = str(input("Please enter your destination country: "))
    time.sleep(5)
    check = str(input("Are you sure you are in " + ori + ", and would like to go to " + dest + "? ")).upper
           
    if check == 'YES':
        enter = 'STOP'
    elif check == 'NO':
        print("Returning to Location Selector")
        enter = 'GO'
    

            
    

##V1##
##Change Currency##
#cr = CurrencyRates()
#output = cr.convert(entry1, entry2, entry3)
#final = round(output, 2)
#print("THE FINAL AMOUNT IS:", final, c2)
```

Comment: add `()` at the end of your input statement.  It should be `.upper()`  I am voting to close this question as a typo

Comment: Due to the typo, `check` becomes `<built-in method upper of str object at ....>` which is never equal to `'YES'`

Answer (score 1):

A simple typo, that's all that was wrong.

In this line of code:

```py
check = str(input("Are you sure you are in " + ori + ", and would like to go to " + dest + "? ")).upper
```

You are attempting to use the method

> .upper()

But your fatal flaw is that you forgot the parentheses.

I changed this:

```py
check = str(input("Are you sure you are in " + ori + ", and would like to go to " + dest + "? ")).upper
```

To this:

```py
check = str(input("Are you sure you are in " + ori + ", and would like to go to " + dest + "? ")).upper()
```

And the code worked perfectly for me

***EXPLANATION***

In the original code, `check` could never be equal to 'YES' or 'NO', because of the typo;

.upper was never recognized as a strings' function and returned with this value:

> <built-in method upper of str object at 0x105fec130>

.upper() on the other IS in fact a valid function for a string and returned with this value when it was supplied with the input of 'yes':

> YES

Comment: Please don't answer questions caused by typos...  That is what the comment section is for.

Comment: I'd shown the code to quite a few people, I dont know how we all managed to miss the typo.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to exit from the loop when a condition is met you can achieve that easily by using `break`. So when your condition is met:

either add bellow `enter = "STOP"` the statement `break` or just replace `enter = "STOP"` for `break`

```py
    if check == 'YES':
        enter = "STOP"
        break
```

or

```py
    if check == 'YES':
        break
```

both should work, I guess you could go with the first answer if you need to keep the state of the variable `enter` otherwise you could just use the second.

The problem with your original code is that you are missing a parenthesis on the declaration of the `upper` method in this line:

```py
check = str(input("Are you sure you are in " + ori + ", and would like to go to " + dest + "? ")).upper
```

instead it should be:

```py
check = str(input("Are you sure you are in " + ori + ", and would like to go to " + dest + "? ")).upper()
```

if you don't add the parenthesis to `upper()` it means you are declaring the object `method` itself not triggering instead what the method actually does. (In this case making the string uppercase)

Comment: Neither is necessary.  The while loop has a terminating condition.  So setting enter to STOP or anything other than GO alone is enough the end the loop

Comment: It was just an informative comment @Alexander

Comment: Thanks for the help.
Both seemed to fix the script.